# Inner-product and vector notation confusion

Tags: vectors, inner-products

I am getting increasingly confused with the notation $< , >$
I know the definition of inner-product (simply, dot product) and I also know what a vector is.

Does it have two different meanings that are completely unrelated?

For example we may define some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as $<i,j>$ I understand the meaning and context behind this.

But, now take the Gradient Inequality theorem.

$f(x) \geq f(y) + <\Delta f(y), x-y>$
What exactly is the notation saying here?

Is $<\Delta f(y), x-y>$ just a shorthand way of expressing the limit for $\frac{f(y+t(x-y))-f(y))}{t}$ ? Does it ever have anything to do with dot product in this instance?

Does this notation have a completely different meaning depending on the context?

Comment: that notation often means inner product (at least when talking about vectors I've only seen it used this way), but it is also used to denoted other types of pairings.

Comment: You said: "For example we may define some vector v∈R2 as <i,j>". What does that mean? Define vector as inner product?

Comment: @user139981 I simply meant that we can use that notation to describe a vector with components i j.

Answer (score 5):

While using left and right brackets is common notation for most introductions to vector algebra/calculus, I've never seen it used in an advanced math textbook. Instead authors like to use $(a,b,c)$ or $a{\bf e}_1+b{\bf e}_2+c{\bf e}_3$ for vectors (the ${\bf e}$'s are the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$--you sometimes see them written as ${\bf i}, {\bf j}, {\bf k}$). The brackets $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ are indeed reserved for the inner product (which is just the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$) in most math past intro courses.

Assuming then that $f: \mathbb{R}_{uv}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, and that $x=(x_1, x_2)$, $y = (y_1, y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the expression from the gradient inequality would be
$$ \langle \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle = \left(\frac{\partial f(y_1, y_2)}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f(y_1,y_2)}{\partial v}\right)\cdot (x_1-y_1, x_2-y_2) = \frac{\partial f(y_1,y_2)}{\partial u}(x_1-y_1)+\frac{\partial f(y_1,y_2)}{\partial v}(x_2-y_2).$$

Comment: thank you heaps for the clarification! :) You are a life-saver